# How to find all neighbour values near the edge in array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, bounding-box

I have an array consisting of `0`s and `1`s.
Firstly, I need to find all neighbour `1`. I managed to do this (the solution is in the link below).

Secondly, I need to choose those, where any element of cluster located near the top boundary.

I can find neighbours with code from [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33766/how-to-compare-fast-the-value-with-the-ones-of-neighbours-in-a-3d-array).

But I need to select only those that are in contact with the top boundary.

Here is an example with a 2D array:

**Input:**

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

**Output:**

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Try it with a kDTree algorhytm. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a connected component labeling problem. You could use [`scipy.ndimage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) to identify the connected components, check which slices of the found objects contain `0` as a starting point and use them to fill the new array:

```
from scipy import ndimage

# labels the connected components with a different digit
x_components, _ = ndimage.measurements.label(a, np.ones((3, 3)))
# returns slices with the bounding boxes
bboxes = ndimage.measurements.find_objects(x_components)
# fills a new array with 1 on those slices
b = np.zeros_like(a)
for bbox in s:
    if bbox[0].start == 0:
        b[bbox] = a[bbox]
```

---

```
print(b)

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```